# Delete all directory with files using gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to delete directory with files inside.

I was trying do something like this:

```
task removeDirectory(type: Delete){
   delete '/app/forDelete/'
}
```

but this task doing nothing, the directory forDelete still exists with files inside

Comment: the path is correct, because if this directory(forDelete) is empty, the task works and it removed this file, but if i add a file to him, task doesn't work and i was trying also without `/`

Comment: Your example is working for me without any problem, with or without a file inside `forDelete`.

Comment: i click green icon play which is near the task in gradle, as i mention it is works if directory is empty, so i run correctly it

Comment: Are you on Windows and does another process have the file open when you try to delete it?

Comment: i'm trying do it on windows and macOS and still working only if directory is empty, i have just opened android studio